# Expand container div with content width

Tags: css, containers, expand

I have the following structure in my application:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="child_container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    ...
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Each child div has a known fixed width, but the application allows more of them to be inserted in the child_container div.

What I'm trying to do is to have the container div expand horizontally when needed, given the total width of the child container.

This is what happens currently:

```
+------ container -------+
+--- child_container ----+
| child1 child2 child3   |
| child4                 |
+------------------------+
```

If I set the child_container div width to a fixed value, I can get it to expand horizontally past the container div, which works despite being a bit ugly:

```
+------ container -------+
+------ child_container -+----+
| child1 child2 child3 child4 |
+------------------------+----+
```

However, that requires recalculating it whenever a new child is added.

Is there a way to do this without using fixed widths for child container, in a way such that the end result is

```
+--------- container ---------+
+------ child_container ------+
| child1 child2 child3 child4 |
+-----------------------------+
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some code. In a fiddle is even better.

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/8XGqs/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8XGqs/1/ illustrates the equivalent of the ascii art above better, I think. Just added width:100% to #container.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
#container, #child_container, .child { 
    position: relative; 
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: @thirtydot because of how some browsers render the html. without telling it the position some browsers won't use the sizes of 'child' elements to increase the size of the containers

Comment: This is good... although you may not need the `position:relative;`

Comment: @wajiw: Which browsers? I assume you're talking about some *really old* browser.

Comment: @thirtydot yeah it's more a habit of mine working with IE6/7 =) not as relevant now but it's a good practice for containers.

Comment: Can you have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/8XGqs/1/ ? It doesn't seem to work on that example, even though everything has "float:left;".

Comment: @Andre I see what you're looking for now. I've updated your code to fix the problem. Using 'white-space:nowrap;' on the container, removing floats on the child and adding 'display:inline-block;' will create a scroll bar when you don't want the children to wrap.

Comment: Thanks, that does it! Do you know why it added the spacing around the elements despite margins, paddings and borders being all set to 0?

Comment: Not sure about that. Might have something to do with the jsfiddle parsers. Can you hit the answer check if this helped you?

Comment: Done.I tested the solution in chrome and firefox, and it shows exactly like in jsfiddle.

Comment: hmm...not sure why that's happening. if you can put a fixed width on that container it would fix it but if those 'children' are dynamic you might have to keep playing with the css

Comment: Fixed it with PatrikAkerstrand's solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Comment: Edited your answer for clubbing the same CSS rules!

Answer (score 35):

Even easier:

```
<style>
    #container{ display: inline-block; }
</style>
```

Comment: Easy to handle per this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544852/ie7-problem-with-display-inline-block)

Answer (score 13):

The parent container won't grow when a child element is added.

```
+------ container -------+
+--- child_container ----+
| child1 child2 child3   |
| child4                 |
+------------------------+
```

but we can avoid the rendering of new one on the next line by using css3 flex box. The sample is placed the below mentioned [path](http://jsfiddle.net/gBSR5/2/)

```
  .products{
            display: -webkit-flex;
            -webkit-flex-flow: row;
            /*-webkit-justify-content: center;*/
        }
        .products > div{
            padding: 0 4em;
        }
```

The result will look like this:

```
+--- child_container ----+|
| child1 child2 child3  ch|ild4 child5  
|                         |
+------------------------+
```

Comment: but the width of container doesn't grow, do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you float everything left including the containing divs, it will work.

Answer (score 2):

The modern solution today would be

```
#child_container {
    display: flex;
}
```

Because `flex-wrap` is by default set to

```
flex-wrap: nowrap;
```

This simple solution works like a charm. And by now also in all relevant browsers.

Answer (score -10):

just set the width of the parent to 120% and done =)

Comment: That will allow a few more elements, what about more stuff coming in?