# div within container won't scroll horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have a dynamic `<ul>` inside a `<div>`, I want that `<div>` to adjust to the size of the `<ul>`. There's no problem with that. But when I wrap everything on a container `<div>` with `overflow: auto`,  the first `<div>` won't adjust to the size of the `<ul>` but to the size of the container, so the `<ul>` and `<li>` break and splatter into the right border of the `<div>` and won't scroll HORIZONTALLY.

The structure loks like:

```
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="iWantToBeHuge">
        <ul>
            <li> Stuff </li>
         </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#mainContainer {

    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;

    float: left;

    overflow: auto;

}

#iWantToBeHuge {

    width: auto;
    height: 95%;

    /*    already tried these    */
    /*    position:absolute;     */
    /*    position:relatve;      */
    /*    float: left;           */

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7EYTh/

Also - Adding a static size to the  is not an option, the contents can be anything between 30px and 3000px wide.

Comment: Your `#iWantToBeHuge` width is set to auto, which adjusts to the parent's size. Change it to like 500px and magic should happen.

Comment: Yeah, i realised I missed that part, there's a reason I havent used a fixed size, the contents can be anything between 30px and 3000px wide.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expand container div with content width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115353/expand-container-div-with-content-width)

Comment: @Jeremy as i stated in the code, I already tried the solutions provided in that question, and they didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jesus Rugama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3808989/jesusrugama)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24593424/2333214) explains why there's no vertical overflow. Since you're looking for horizontal overflow,

Currently nothing is horizontally overflowing your container. If you want scrollbar, you should create overflow, for example

```
#iWantToBeHuge {
  width: auto;
  height: 95%;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7EYTh/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldnt be using `height: 95%;` , this means when you use relative height the element uses the parent to determine the size. So you are telling `#iWantToBeHuge` to use 95% of `#mainContainer` height.

If you want to see a scrollbar try changing `#iWantToBeHuge` height to a bigger size than `#mainContainer` ie: 600px. Or just remove the height style so it can adapt to the `ul`.

EDIT:
try using this CSS for horizontal scroll:

```
#mainContainer{
    width: 200px;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#iWantToBeHuge ul li{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the problem is not the vertical scroll but the horizontal. And I can't use a fixed size for either, the content's size vary greatly.

Comment: @whitelionV you didn't mention it in question. usually when you say `scroll`, especially by the looks of your demo, people assumes it's vertical `scroll`

Comment: @TilwinJoy I edited the question tried making it a lil' more clear.