# CSS div expand horizontally instead of vertically

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place content into a div and make it expand horizontally instead of vertically. I've looked up methods on Stackoverflow and Google, but for odd some reason none of them works.
.group-container is the container and .group div are placed withing the container.

My html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Website Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scroll.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<!-- HEADER BEGIN -->
<div class="header">


<img src="logo2.png" class="logo" alt="" />

<div class="right-menu-holder">


<a href="" class="menu-links">LOGIN</a>
&nbsp;
<input type="button" class="searchbtn" value="SEARCH" />

<div class="right-side-container">
<input type="text" class="search-field" />
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

</div>
<!-- HEADER END -->
    <img src="left_arrow.png" id="arrowL" />
    <img src="right_arrow.png" id="arrowR" />
    <div class="clear"></div>

<!-- GROUP CONTAINER AND INNER BEGINS-->
<div class="group-container">

<div class="group" id="group">
<font class="trending">Trending 1</font>
<br />
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RWfjeQJlNSc/mqdefault.jpg" class="thumb" />
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RWfjeQJlNSc/mqdefault.jpg" class="thumb" />
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RWfjeQJlNSc/mqdefault.jpg" class="thumb" />
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RWfjeQJlNSc/mqdefault.jpg" class="thumb" />
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RWfjeQJlNSc/mqdefault.jpg" class="thumb" />
<br />
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RWfjeQJlNSc/mqdefault.jpg" class="thumb" />
<br />
</div>



<div class="group" id="group">
<font class="trending">Trending 2</font>
<br />
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RWfjeQJlNSc/mqdefault.jpg" class="thumb" />
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RWfjeQJlNSc/mqdefault.jpg" class="thumb" />
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RWfjeQJlNSc/mqdefault.jpg" class="thumb" />
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RWfjeQJlNSc/mqdefault.jpg" class="thumb" />
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RWfjeQJlNSc/mqdefault.jpg" class="thumb" />
<br />
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RWfjeQJlNSc/mqdefault.jpg" class="thumb" />
<br />
</div>



<div class="group" id="group">
<font class="trending">Trending 3</font>
<br />
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RWfjeQJlNSc/mqdefault.jpg" class="thumb" />
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RWfjeQJlNSc/mqdefault.jpg" class="thumb" />
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RWfjeQJlNSc/mqdefault.jpg" class="thumb" />
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RWfjeQJlNSc/mqdefault.jpg" class="thumb" />
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RWfjeQJlNSc/mqdefault.jpg" class="thumb" />
<br />
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RWfjeQJlNSc/mqdefault.jpg" class="thumb" />
<br />
</div>



<div class="group" id="group">
<font class="trending">Trending 4</font>
<br />
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RWfjeQJlNSc/mqdefault.jpg" class="thumb" />
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RWfjeQJlNSc/mqdefault.jpg" class="thumb" />
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RWfjeQJlNSc/mqdefault.jpg" class="thumb" />
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RWfjeQJlNSc/mqdefault.jpg" class="thumb" />
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RWfjeQJlNSc/mqdefault.jpg" class="thumb" />
<br />
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/RWfjeQJlNSc/mqdefault.jpg" class="thumb" />
<br />
</div>


<div class="clear"></div>





</div>
<!-- GROUP CONTAINER AND INNER END -->



<!-- FOOTER BEGIN -->
<div class="footer"> &copy; 2015 Website</div>
<!-- FOOTER END -->
</body>
</html>
```

And the css for the two div

```
.group-container{
    width:1296px;
    height:83%;
    margin-left:2.5%;
    margin-top:20px;
    overflow-x:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
    position:relative
}

#group{
    white-space:normal;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:1296px;
}
```

Comment: Aside: Consider using proper HTML semantics (header should be in `<header>`, nav menu in `<nav>`, footer content in `<footer>` and so on). Also, have you considered frameworks such as Bootstrap which provides a flexible [column layout](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-grid-system.php)?

Comment: Is 1296px the *minimum* width required of the DIV? If so, you can just change `width: 1296px;` in `.group-container` to `min-width: 1296px;` and remove the width and display setters in `#group`. In fact, I suspect you can maybe get rid of the `#group` class altogether in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a lot to consider here, it depends on what your going for. Generally speaking, if you want your `<img>`s to lay horizontally you need to make the height of `.group-container` less than two rows worth of images. So if your `<img>`s are `180px` high, set `.group-container` at least `180px`.

```
.group-container {
    height:200px;
}
```

You'll however run into other issue when you start adding more images. As soon as the images will take up more width than the the `1296px`, they'll start pilling up in rows. You'll need to keep setting the `.group-container` wider. (Not to mention that it won't fit on any screen at this point).

A good workaround you can look at is setting the CSS on your images `float:left;` and setting a fixed height on your `.group-container`. If you want to have enclose the long strip of images into something that fits on the screen, put your `.group-container` into another `div` element and give it a `width` and a `height`, as well as `overflow-x: auto;`

```
.group-container {
    height:200px;
}
.group-container img {
    float:left;
}
.group-container-parent {
    width:100%;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

And your HTML code would be something like

```
<div class="group-container-parent">
    <div class="group-container">
        <img ... />
        <img ... />
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And as @trashr0x pointed out, good semantics would really help, as well as avoid the `<font>` tag and using CSS spacing for your line breaks

Answer (score 0):

i think this link can help you.

[Expand container div with content width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115353/expand-container-div-with-content-width)